# ¿Cómo convertir 'HH:MM' a una hora GMT particular en Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, localtime, horas

Suponga que tiene una variable que almacena el siguiente formato de zona horaria como tipo cadena:

```
timezone = '(GMT -5:00)'
```

Ahora tiene las siguientes horas, que se configuraron en `GMT -4:00` y como tipos de cadena:

```
tiempo1 = '4:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
tiempo2 = '9:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
```

¿Cómo se puede usar la variable `timezone` para cambiar los valores `tiempo1` y `tiempo2` a sus horas locales correspondientes? es decir:

```
tiempo1 = '3:00' #am  (GMT -5:00)
tiempo2 = '8:00' #am  (GMT -5:00)
```

Comment: No entiendo porque manejas la fecha como string. ¿Cual es la dificultad de la operación?

Comment: Esa fecha es obtenida de un elemento web que guardó la información como tipo string y no como tipo datetime @CandidMoe

Comment: @NoahVerner todo es un string en la web... el uso y la transformacion, depende de vos....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, no es la gran cosa pero es trabajo honesto:

```
import datetime

timezone = '(GMT -5:00)'
timezone = timezone.replace("(", "").replace("GMT ", "").replace(":","").replace(")", "")
gmt_hours = int(timezone[:2])

gmt_less_4_hours = -4

time_difference = abs(gmt_hours - gmt_less_4_hours)

time1 = "04:00" #am  (GMT -4:00)
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M")
time1 -= datetime.timedelta(hours=time_difference)
time1 = time1.strftime('%H:%M')
print(time1)

time2 = '9:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, "%H:%M")
time2 -= datetime.timedelta(hours=time_difference)
time2 = time2.strftime('%H:%M')
print(time2)
```

**Output:**

> 03:00
>
> 08:00

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, si quieres extraer la hora mencionada en timezone, este método me parece más claro, más seguro y que requiere muchos menos recorridos a la cadena: `timezone = int(timezone[len("(GMT "):timezone.find(":")])`

Comment: O usando el método removesuffix de las versiones más nuevas: `timezone = timezone.removesuffix("(GMT ")
timezone = timezone[:timezone.find(":")]`